# Regarding drive for heaters

Tags: power, control, pid-controller

Am working for a private organisation. We have one hot air oven for curing application. Here we are using 15kw heaters(1.5kw x 10nos). My question is, shall I use 15kw Variable frequency drive for temp controller. Bcoz I need PID logic to maint the exact temperature in oven. Please guide me.

Comment: I wouldn't think the frequency would matter to a heater.  You would need to pulse the heaters - turn them on for some time period, then off, then repeat.  The ratio of on/(on+off) gives you the effective power reduction.

Answer (score 2):

A VFD is not the right device, and might well have problems because the drive would not be able to detect the expected back EMF for sensorless operation.

There are two typical  strategies used- time proportioning where the heater is turned and off for varying duty cycles. The period might be a few seconds if solid-state switching is used, up to perhaps 20-30 seconds or longer if a mechanical contactor is used.

The second method is to use a phase-control method to provide smoothly varying power, which of course requires semiconductor switching. This is less desirable because of the heat and electrical noise caused by the (usually) thyristors. It's also a bit less desirable from a control point of view because of nonlinearity. If your heating is primarily IR such as halogen tube heaters you may need to use this method because the variations would otherwise be too large.

The most straightforward method is to buy a self-tuning PID temperature controller and sensor, and marry that to a suitable power switch, and most industrial applications use exactly that approach.

Answer (score 1):

A VFD is built to maintain a given speed at an axle regardless which counter torque is applied to it. You don't have an axle, so it can measure neither speed nor torque. It simple would go into failure mode.

You don't need a *PID* controller. That is because the time constant of your controlled system are so long there isn't any relevant *D* component in it to measure. *PI* ist sufficient. *I* alone may be sufficient, too.

Your problem is controlling the temperature and the heat transfer from the heater to your assembly. Two possible approaches

- close loop control: continously measure the temperature at your assembly. If it's a big, nonuniform thing which heats up at different speeds, measure at different places. Use these temperature values to control your heater.
- open loop control: do a test series. Either with temperature measurements, or just measurements ok/not ok for different styles of heating. Find the biggest influences from the assembly on the heating. On the real pieces, excercise a tailored *heating program*, depending on the variables found during the tests.

What are you curing? Paint? Glue? Plastic film? What is it on? Metal, plastic, wood?